# PHP sqlsrv_connect is not defined

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I am using hostinger web hosting server and added sqlsrv extension in php configuration in hostinger account.
Hostinger technical team confirmed that below functions are enabled in my hostinger account.

```
[1792] => sqlsrv_connect
[1793] => sqlsrv_close
[1794] => sqlsrv_commit
 ...
```

But when I tried to connect to our remote mssql server using sqlsrv_connect, "Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()"

My test code is below.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$serverName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxx", "UID"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxxxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

And the response of this php script is below.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> sqlsrv_connect() in
> /home/uxxxxxxxxx/domains/xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx/public_html/sql.php:8 Stack
> trace: #0 {main} thrown in
> /home/uxxxxxxxxx/domains/xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx/public_html/sql.php on line
> 8

Hostinger technical team said that it's code problem, and sqlsrv extension is enabled for my account.
Have you any experienced with this kind of issues ?
What's the solution for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running on a Linux host? `sqlsrv` is not supported for Linux. Otherwise, run `phpinfo()` and see what that says about the `sqlsrv` extension. If it shows that it's not enabled then take a screenshot and go back to Hostinger's technical team and ask them to fix it.

Comment: are you sure that Hostinger is using Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL)? All I find is, that they use MariaDB. if so, you should try using a different PHP extension: [PHP MySQL connect](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular
My hostinger account is running on a Linux host.
But hostinger technical team said that they provides sqlsrv.
I already run phpinfo() and checked that sqlsrv is enabled.

Comment: @jumper85
Thanks for your comment.
Of course, hostinger is using mysql for DB.
What I am asking is not that.
I am trying to connect to remote mssql server from hostinger hosted php site.
For data migration, need to connect to remote mssql server.

Comment: @markOriend ok, didn't see that. for me this clearly seems like a configuration issue, not an issue with your code. because you already tried the `phpinfo()` suggestion, I think you need to contact their support again. something doesn't seem right there.